# Git clients over a network drive

Tags: windows, git, samba, tortoisegit

If I have a network drive with a git repo checkout, for example, samba drive on a windows machine (A) connected to Linux machine (B) where the local checkout is. Is there a way for clients on A - who can see the drive - to do git operations through the the ssh access defined on B?

Comment: Why would you use ssh access if you have the drive mounted over the network already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filesystem on which the repository resides, should not make a big difference, from the perspective of git. Git just stores the data inside the directory structure, and in the root of the directory tree there is the .git-dir to keep the data (You can configure it to be elsewhere, but that's a different story).

So access to the repository is only defined by system level access configuration details. Anyone on A, who has access to the directory can see the repository. If he has write access, he can also do operations like commits into the repo. The same goes for B, so every user who can do stuff in the dir, can also make modifications to the repository. SSH-access or local shell doesn't make a difference in this setup.